# Angular 8 - blink td when its value changes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular 8 in my project. I'm using angular material to render my table.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="CurrentBill">
        <td mat-cell [appHighlight] *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.CurrentBill }} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I have a directive as below:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() public number: any;
  @Input() public input: any;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if(changes.input){
      console.log(`${changes.input} changed.`);
    }
  }
}
```

Question: this directive only works on input and I don't know how to make it work when the `td` value changes. I need to get the old value and the new value. So I can highlight it only if the value has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="CurrentBill">
            <td mat-cell [appHighlight]="element.CurrentBill" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.CurrentBill }} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

and

```
import { Directive, OnChanges, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input() public appHighlight: any;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.appHighlight && changes.appHighlight.currentValue != changes.appHighlight.previousValue) {
      console.log('value', changes.appHighlight.currentValue);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: thanks Francesco, this solution works but not to the extend that I wanted. is there anyway to get the old value and the new value in the directive? I'm trying to highlight it only if the value changed. atm, the previous value comes out as undefined

Comment: @Daniel what do you mean by old and new values?

Comment: I have a table that its values are updating every 5 min and I want to blink the ones that have changed. if I could get the old value and the new value, i could compare them and if they are different, blink the cell.

Comment: I have modified the directive according to your needs

Comment: @Francescon the "storedValue" is always undefined.

Comment: I did a stackblitz for you, I removed the storedValue which was redundant, since simpleChange has both currentValue and previousValue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-au155n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts